# Omitting a list of observations in sas sql

Tags: sql, merge, sas

I'm trying to create a table in sas that will take observations from a specific column as long as they aren't list in another column in another table.

I've used the code:

```
proc sql; 
create table tbl as
select a.var1, a.var2, a.var3 from
tblA as a, tblB as b
where a.var1~=b.var1;
quit;
```

Would it be because I've assigned b as a table I'm not selecting a variable from? or is my condition just incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect, you need to tell the tables how to join (where the equality is) THEN tell them that you only want those that dont match.

A left join is used for this:

```
  select a.var1, a.var2, a.var3
  from 
   tblA as a
   left join tblB as b on a.var1 = b.var1
  where
   b.var1 is null
```

Where `a` are the values you want that dont match `b`.

[See SAS SQL join examples for more](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473691.htm)

This can also be accomplished using [`NOT IN`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473689.htm)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Think I'll be able to use this condition for another problem. Big Thanks.